# Django model design issue with relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I have an problem where I can’t decide how to design the models for the following scenario

- I want to create a companies table that will hold a list of companies. This table will have a comment field in it
- I want that comment field to be able to hold multiple comments that are dated
- A company can have multiple comments but a comment can only belong to only one company

Here the Comments table

```
class Comments(model.Models):
    date  = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment_text = models.TextField(required=True)
```

If I create the Companies table like this;

```
class Companies(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comments, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Then I can only attach one comment to one specific row of the Companies table

If I create the Companies table like this;

```
class Companies(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    comment = models.ManyToManyField(Comments)
```

Then a comment can belong to multiple companies which I don’t want.

In the Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/ there is only one other options left which is the one-to-one mapping and this is clearly not what I want.

How can achieve what I want ?

Comment: Just add foreign key  relationship in comment for company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Comment(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date  = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment_text = models.TextField()
```

When accessing comments of a certain company, It will be;

`comments = company.comments.all()`

Comment: I guess that was what Daniel was referring to correct? I wanted to have the comment field directly in the Company table (to make things easier for display purpose). Let me know if this is not possible in which case I will accept your answer

Comment: What Daniel said is what I have Implemented. The ForeignKey should be in the Comment pointing out to the Company. Where are you displaying this? In Django admin?

Comment: Yes that is correct, display is in Django admin hence my fear of not being able to display the comment field if it doesn't belong to the company field (still newbie in Django). My idea about having comment field in company table was to have all information displayed in one go in the admin just by displaying the company table.

Comment: It's a good idea if you first finish designing your models. Once you have them working, You should try to tweak Django admin to achieve the display you want. You can check out the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/).

Answer (score 0):

Just put the ForeignKey on Comment, pointing to Company. This does exactly what you want.